# Differences in APIs to access Kerberos

Tags: javascript, api, security, passwords, kerberos

Could someone explain the differences between:

- Kerberos API
- GSS-API
- krb5 API

What should be used for which use-case?

If i want to set a password and the principals for user-accounts via API, what API should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, today's Kerberos is version 5, so point 1 and 3 are the same. Kerberos is a low level authetication mech whereas GSS-API is a high level API supporting multiple mechs through their OIDs. In this case, you use Kerberos indirectly through GSS-API and OID [`1.2.840.113554.1.2.2`](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/submissions/1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.html). You never use Kerberos directly.

What type of API do you want to design? Changing AD passwords should best happen directly through a user...unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: I try to explain what i need to do. I have a Novell eDirectory (Part of Novell Identity Manager). Now ew added a OpenLDAP system as destination system to our IDM (via LDAP driver). I tranfer user accounts from eDirectory to OpenLDAP via LDAP driver. Now we also need to use Kerberos with the OpenLDAP system (but not on the eDirectory system!!). I have the user passwords stored in eDirectoy, if i transport it within the LDAP driver i get a hashed version in OpenLDAP....

Comment: ...To come to the point ;) : I need to find a way to transfer the passwords from eDirectory to Kerberos-Keys for all Users (so i have to use the API). See my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448361/novell-edirectory-ldap-driver-kerberos-passwords

Comment: This is something completely different and has nothing to do with the question. What type of KDC do you use? You should really go to serverfault.com. You are trying to use a directory server as an data backend for a Kerberos-enabled network.

Comment: What do you mean by: "...What type of KDC..." ? We use MIT Kerberos with CentOS and OpenLDAP. The Kerberos with OpenLDAP as data bakend are allready running. Everything is fine with this. The only thing i need to do, is to get the passwords from our eDirectory to Kerberos (using something like krb5_c_string_to_key() )...but i actually doesn´t find a practicable way to go...We want to avoid telling all our users to change password!!!

Comment: New passwords would be a good security measure. Don't you have a password expiry policy?

Comment: We have more than 40000 users and need to keep the passwords! No, we don´t use a password expiry policy.

Comment: first of all, you have a security flaw. You should move the question to serverfault.com, that would be a better place for admin tasks.